# Why is GeoDjango not returning my GeoJSON in SRID 4326?

Tags: geojson, geodjango

I have a model with point data stored in srid 2953.
When I serialize this data, I assumed that GeoDjando would convert this to valid GeoJSON by converting the coordinates to SRID 4326.
Maybe I need to specificly tell it to convert this?
From what I have read I understand that CRS has been depreciated from GeoJSON, and that it is only valid in SRID 4326?

```
class Hpnrecord(models.Model):
    ...
    geom = models.PointField(srid=2953, null=True)
```

Later in a serializer I have:

```
class HpnrecordSerializer(serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
        geo_field = "geom"
        model = Hpnrecord
```

When I view the returned data I am getting this:

> {
> "type": "FeatureCollection",
> "features": [
> {
> "type": "Feature",
> "geometry": {
> "type": "Point",
> "coordinates": [
> 2594598.985,
> 7425392.375
> ]
> },
> "properties": {
> }
> },

as you can see, the coordinates are being displayed as Easting and Northing (the same as what is stored in the model), and not being converted to SRID 4326. My endpoint is expecting to receive this in srid 4326.

How do I specify that I expect the serializaiton to be in SRID 4326?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might have noticed, SRID transformations are not done automatically. I have 2 suggestions for you:

**Suggestion 1: Store the data in the desired SRID**

Before you store the data, you convert it first to your desired srid of 4326. Your model would change:

```
class Hpnrecord(models.Model):
    ...
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True)
```

Storing the data would look like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

...

point = Point(x, y, srid=2953)
point.transform(4326)
model_instance.geom = point
model_instance.save()
```

**Suggestion 2: Use the serializer's `to_representation()`**

You keep your models as they are and you convert the SRID on the fly using the serializer's `to_representation()` method, see the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior). Note that converting it on the fly will result in a speed penalty, but you can leave the models as they are.

```
class HpnrecordSerializer(serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
        geo_field = "geom"
        model = Hpnrecord
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """Convert `geom` to srid 4326."""
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret['geom'].transform(4326)
        return ret
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was assuming (incorrectly) that Django would convert to srid 4326 for me (your option 2 version). For me this actually ended up being a good thing as it forced me to rethink why I was storing in other srid and switching model to 4326 would end up being a better solution long term. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for covering this, although I had to do something different with Suggestion 2:

transform() by default transforms the geometry in place. I don't save the instance so it doesn't get committed to disk, but it does rewrite it before the GeoJSON serializer gets it.

    def to_representation(self, instance):  
         """Convert geom to srid 4269."""  
         instance.geom.transform(4269)  
         ret = super().to_representation(instance)  
         return ret

Comment: Argh, I was struggling with formatting in that comment. Let's try this again:

Thanks for covering this, although I had to do something different with Suggestion 2:

transform() by default transforms the geometry in place. I don't save the instance so it doesn't get committed to disk, but it does rewrite it before the GeoJSON serializer gets it.

I changed this to call `instance.geom.transform(4326)` first, then called the `super()` function and pass in the instance.

Comment: It looks like @MichaelBacon is right, `transform()` transforms the coordinates in place. I will update the post in order to make it right. @MichaelBacon there is also a `clone` parameter, which you can use: `ret['geom'] = ret['geom'].transform(4326, clone=True)` See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.transform)

Comment: The problem with that is that the return dictionary includes a string, not a GEOS geometry object, so when I put in ret['geom'].transform(...) I got something like "str has no attribute transform" or some such error. Calling it on the instance before calling the super() function worked fine.